# Which version of java should be installed to support pycharm 1.5.4 for Linux

Tags: pycharm

I have experienced consistent crash after I install pycharm 1.5.4 for ubuntu 10.04 with 
jre1.5.0_22 or jre1.6.0_27. After the crashes, I found that the log folder contains simply empty folders without useful information.

From the [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/index.html), the company only indicates that "Sun JDK 1.6. Open JDK is not supported" without mentioning what is supported. Also I have difficulties to differentiate the sun open jdk or sun jdk.

Question> Now I am moving to ubuntu 11.04 and plan for a fresh installation. So what is the right java version for pycharm 1.5.4?

Comment: In year 2015 pyCharm works with Oracle JRE 1.6+ or OpenJDK 1.7+. This means with ubuntu 14.04 you can use the package `default-jre`.

Answer (score 1):

Sun (Oracle) JDK 1.6.0_27 is recommended. The page says exactly this. In other words, Sun JDK is required, OpenJDK is not supported.

Comment: I still don't see where the page says which version of JDK is supported. It only mentions which one is not supported.

Comment: It says under System requirements: Sun JDK 1.6. Open JDK is not supported. Which means that Sun JDK is required, but Open JDK is not supported.

Comment: To my understanding, that specification is by no means a good way to illustrate the prerequisite of the software. By indicating what is NOT supported implied nothing about what is supported.

Comment: Wording may be confusing, and we'll consider correcting it, thanks for pointing to this problem.